# How to get a valid JWT from testing enviroment from Google using Next.js 14

Tags: testing, google-oauth, cypress, next-auth, next.js14

I have an basic app in next.js 14 with next-auth and typescript. I'm looking to test protected pages using Google OAuth and the steps mentioned here: [Google Auth](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/google-authentication#Setting-Google-app-credentials-in-Cypress).

I have the current custom command `cy.loginByGoogleApi()` to fetch the user info. But when I try to manually set up the `access_token` as a the  `next-auth.session-token` cookie in the test, It just says a server error from Next telling the next message

```
[next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error Invalid Compact JWE {
  message: 'Invalid Compact JWE',
  stack: 'JWEInvalid: Invalid Compact JWE\n' +
    '    at compactDecrypt (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/jwe/compact/decrypt.js:18:15)\n' +
    '    at jwtDecrypt (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/jwt/decrypt.js:10:61)\n' +
    '    at Object.decode (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/jwt/index.js:44:52)\n' +
    '    at async Object.session (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/session.js:25:34)\n' +
    '    at async AuthHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:161:37)\n' +
    '    at async getServerSession (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:126:21)\n' +
    '    at async getPassport (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./services/SecurityService.ts:16:21)\n' +
    '    at async RootLayout (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/layout.tsx:27:20)',
  name: 'JWEInvalid'
```

According to the NextAuth documentation, referes to [this error](https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error) .

Should I enconde some of the token returned from the Google Authorization Server?

It is posible to mockup the `next-auth.session-token` from a test enviroment with the Cypress recomendated config? Thanks in advice.

```js
// options.ts (NextAuthOptions)

export const options: NextAuthOptions = {

  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,

  providers: [

    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string
    }),


  ],



  // Callback implemented to attach the user id to the session object.
  callbacks: {

    // Return true if the user is allowed to sign in. Otherwise, return false.
    // user: Contains user's details fetched from the provider method.
    // account: Object contains information about the login, such as the provider used. 
    async signIn({ user, account }) {


      try {

        // If user and account were provided...
        if (user && account && user.name && user.email) {

          // If provider is from google...
          if (account.provider === 'google') {

            try {

              // Get User details
              let userResponse : ServiceResponse = await UserService.getUserByEmail(user?.email!)

              // If the user was not found...
              if ( ! userResponse.success) {
                //custom logic to search or create account for user
                return true;
              }

            } catch (error) {

              return false;

            }

          }

        }

      } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Something went wrong while trying to login the user. ${error}`)
      }

      return false

    },



    // Add important information to the token, such as organizationId, role and id, from the given user.
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile }) {

      if (user) {

        token.id = user.id
        token.organizationId = user.organizationId;
        token.role = user.role;

      }

      return token;

    },

    // Add important fields to the session object, such as user details and token details.
    session: ({ session, token }) => {

      return {
        ...session,
        user: {
          ...session.user,
          id: token.id,
          organizationId: token.organizationId,
          role: token.role
        },
      }

    },

  },

  jwt: {

    // Define a max age for sessions of 24 hrs.
    maxAge: 400 * 60 * 60,

  },


}
```

The Cypress Commands file

```js
Cypress.Commands.add( 'loginByGoogleApi', () => {

  //cy.log('Logging in to Google')
  
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
    body: {
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      client_id: Cypress.env('googleClientId'),
      client_secret: Cypress.env('googleClientSecret'),
      refresh_token: Cypress.env('googleRefreshToken'),
    },
  })
  
  .then(( response ) : void => {

    cy.log(' response 1')
    cy.log( JSON.stringify( response, undefined, 2 ) )

    const { access_token, id_token } = response.body

    cy.request({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo',
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}` },
    })
    
    .then((response) => {

      cy.log(' response 2')
      cy.log( JSON.stringify( response, undefined, 2 ) )


      const userItem = {
        token: id_token,
        user: {
          googleId: response.body.sub,
          email: response.body.email,
          givenName: response.body.given_name,
          familyName: response.body.family_name,
          imageUrl: response.body.picture,
        },
      }

      cy.log(' response 3')
      cy.log( JSON.stringify( response, undefined, 2 ) )

      cy.setCookie('next-auth.session-token', access_token)

      window.localStorage.setItem('googleCypress', JSON.stringify(userItem))


      cy.visit('/')
    })
  })




} )
```

I tried to follow the steps in the Cypress Documentation without success.